# JSFiddle shows different graph than my browser

Tags: javascript, highcharts, jsfiddle

See: http://jsfiddle.net/j9tx8hL1/

By using the 'null'-values I want to achieve that there are no lines displayed in the graph, for instance no visible line for series4.

```
var series4 = [[56,null],[65,null],[80,null]];
```

In JSFiddle, this works.
However, in my browser my application still shows something different.
See: https://www.screencast.com/t/jRr6nlivwF0M

I can't find out what could be the cause of this, both situations should be exactly the same, but apparently are not. 
Has anybody here got any advice where to search for a cause?

Comment: are you using the same source files?

Comment: ... I'm ashamed. I was using an older version in my application indeed...
Thanks!